# What happens to Kreacher after Yaxley breach Grimauld's Place secret?

Tags: harry-potter, house-elves

Kreacher is the house-elf of Grimmauld Place. From the death of the last black inhabitants, he was left alone until Sirius moved in. Then his ownership passed on to Harry.

Harry had him work at Hogwarts until DH when he had him back to Grimmauld Place. Some trust started to build between them, but after the Ministry of Magic chaotic escape, the house became accessible to Death Eathers (or at least presumably). Harry even thought about Kreacher for some time, and how he would be saddened by their disappearance and the invasion of the Death Eaters.

Nevertheless, we never get to know what happens to him afterward, IIRC. Is there any information about him after Harry, Ron and Hermione broke into the Ministry of Magic?

Answer (score 9):

Kreacher led the house-elves of Hogwarts in the battle against the Death Eaters during the attack on Hogwarts, for Harry Potter, defender of the house-elves, and for the sake of the memory of his long-dead master Regulus, bringing to mind that, although he was a Death Eater, he had died fighting Lord Voldemort.

> The house-elves of Hogwarts swarmed into the entrance hall, screaming
>   and waving carving knives and cleavers, and at their head, the locker
>   of Regulus Black bouncing on his chest, was Kreacher, his bullfrog's
>   voice audible even above this din: "Fight! Fight! Fight for my Master,
>   defender of house-elves! Fight the Dark Lord, in the name of brave
>   Regulus! Fight!"
>
> They were hacking and stabbing at the ankles and
>   shins of Death Eaters, their tiny faces alive with malice, and
>   everywhere Harry looked Death Eaters were folding under sheer weight
>   of numbers, overcome by spells, dragging arrows from wounds, stabbed
>   in the leg by elves, or else simply attempting to escape, but
>   swallowed by the oncoming horde.
>
> ***Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 31, The Battle of Hogwarts**

It is not specified whether he survived the Battle of Hogwarts, but Harry, who wanted to go to bed after the battle, wondered if Kreacher could bring him a sandwich, implying that he did in fact survive. It is unknown if he continued to work in the Hogwarts kitchens or entered the service of the Potter family, or possibly both.(from the wiki)

Comment: Thanks Luna! Love your name btw. My 2nd fav HP char(after Hermione)